# Is local proxy suitable for video stream?

Tags: android, video, proxy, android-mediaplayer

I am using a local proxy built with `ServerSocket`, just like what [NPR](https://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/source/browse/Npr/src/org/npr/android/news/StreamProxy.java) is doing. However, if the video is larger than 10MB, the `MediaPlayer` crushes almost every time(The `MediaPlayer` is sending `HttpRequest` frequently, maybe, I am doning too much to respond the request, and the `MediaPlayer` got no responding.).

So, is it impossible to use local proxy to stream mp4 videos?
Or, can I do something to avoid the crash?

Comment: when it crashes, what is the error?

Comment: @user2310289 I've got a totally black screen. The `MediaPlayer` is not responding but keeps sending `HttpRequest` with "range" header to my local server. There is no error, with no responding and a black screen.

Comment: you may have to post some code then

Comment: I use a proxy for much larger videos. That's definitely not the issue.

Comment: Thank U, Dave. Your answer is useful to me.

Comment: I tried to add some code. However, it is too long, and I find nothing to be attatched here, because the key code is almost same as what NPR looks like.

Comment: Hi Dave, @Dave  Could you tell me your video format when you using local server to stream the much larger video? I could not stream the mp4 video successfully, instead, I used HLS.

Comment: What is the failure? The largest videos I stream are usually H.264, but the size of the video should not cause failure. Are you watching the requests and responses? If you don't control the server, use Wireshark on the device or get feedback some other way.

Comment: I can see how the server responses. When I seek to a position where the media player has not buffered, the media player keeps requesting bytes from some different offset, and requesting on and on. The server handles every request and the responses are definitely same as the requests. @Dave

Comment: When you seek, are you calling `seekTo` or are you making a request on your own and simply substituting data sent to the `MediaPlayer`?

Comment: I am calling `seekTo`. The requests are posted by the `MeiaPlayer` itself, and then my local server handles the requests. @Dave